# How to allow double forward slashes when upload file using Laravel League s3

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

There is a directory in S3 bucket named `uploads//` and I want to upload my files there since it is already using in existing web app and when I tried to upload to `uploads//` with Laravel league, it is ignoring one slash from two. So I added `///` and it is also ignored and file uploaded to a new folder with `uploads`.

Example:

I want the file to be uploaded as

```
uploads//attachments/filename.jpg
```

Currently one slash ignored and uploaded as

```
uploads/attachments/filename.jpg
```

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
// assume path as '/attachments/filename.jpg'
if($isPathDifferent==0){
    $path =  'uploads//'. $path;
}
$upload = Storage::disk('s3')->store($path, file_get_contents($file));
Storage::disk('s3')->setVisibility($path, 'public');
```

Please note that I cannot change the name `uploads//` because it has lot of resources and usage.

Comment: And [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) doesn't work?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans It works but the file is not uploading `The specified key does not exist.`

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans when I encode and upload s3 create new folder as: `uploads%2F%2Fattachments/1626839144_m.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Please apply following solution, it should fix your problem

```
$path = Storage::disk('s3')->put('uploads/', $file);
```

Comment: This not provide solution to my problem since it has another path segnment as example uploads//atachment/filename.jpg